# How to use switch statement with Enumerations C#

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I want to use a switch statement in order to avoid many if's. So I did this:

```
        public enum Protocol
        {
             Http,
             Ftp
        }

        string strProtocolType = GetProtocolTypeFromDB();

        switch (strProtocolType)
        {
            case Protocol.Http:
                {
                    break;
                }
            case Protocol.Ftp:
                {
                    break;
                }
        }
```

but I have a problem of comparing an Enum and a String. So if I added Protocol.Http.ToString() there is another error because it allows only CONSTANT evaluation. If I change it to this

```
        switch (Enum.Parse(typeof(Protocol), strProtocolType))
```

It's not possible also. So, it's possible to use in my case a switch statement or not?

Comment: I guess you must cast the result of Enum.Parse to Protocol

Comment: What are you getting back from `GetFromProtocolTypeFromDB` is it `enum` or string ?

Comment: Why doesn't `GetFromProtocolTypeFromDB` return a `Protocol` instead of a `string`?

Comment: I misspelled! It's GetProtocolTypeFromDB() returns a string which represents the Protocol

Comment: what @TimSchmelter meant (I guess) is that having GetProtocolTypeFromDB returning a Protocol and not a string (that is making the Enum.Parse, casting business inside GetProtocolTypeFromDB ) would really improve the overall quality of your code. You should give a try to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the `Enum.Parse` result to `Protocol` to make it work.

```
switch ((Protocol)Enum.Parse(typeof(Protocol), strProtocolType))
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative using the generic API:

```
Protocol protocol;
if(Enum.TryParse(GetFromProtocolTypeFromDB(), out protocol)
{
    switch (protocol)
    {
        case Protocol.Http:
            {
                break;
            }
        case Protocol.Ftp:
            {
                break;
            }
        // perhaps a default
    }
} // perhaps an else
```

Although frankly, it might be easier just to test with `==` or `string.Equals` (if you want case-insensitivity, etc) rather than using `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
    public enum Protocol
    {
         Http,
         Ftp
    }

    string strProtocolType = GetFromProtocolTypeFromDB();
    Protocol protocolType = (Protocol)Enum.Parse(typeof(Protocol), strProtocolType);

    switch (protocolType)
    {
        case Protocol.Http:
            {
                break;
            }
        case Protocol.Ftp:
            {
                break;
            }
    }
```